# Laravel how to redirect from root folder to public folder

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'am using `<Virtualhost>` in my httpd.conf apache in my local machine, but what can I do if I don't have access to that file in my shared hosting? how to redirect it using .htaccess? using Laravel 4

Comment: Can you SSH into your hosting?

Comment: [Laravel 4 in Shared Hosting](http://crynobone.com/posts/3/laravel-4-in-shared-hosting)